# Selenium: reuse existing browser session, instead of opening new windows using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm looking for a way to connect with an existing site in Microsoft Edge using PowerShell and be able to leave it open all day long on a user's computer to use multiple times a day. The URL the code is navigating to is a web based application where they record information they gathered about a project they are working on. This is how it records their production so supervisors can see how much they do per day. I've found a solution on YouTube that allows me to pull up the login page of the site. But, once they log in, my code will say "Duplicate or refreshed site" instead of allowing the user to perform the same task they did the last time the script was ran. Here's what I've got:

```
$ScriptPath = "C:\Users\lpeder6\Documents\PowerShell\Selenium"

Add-Type -Path "$ScriptPath\WebDriver.dll"

$Edge = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver

$Edge.Navigate().GoToUrl('http://omega2010.com')
```

All of the sites advice I've seen has been for Python, C#, and other programming languages. I'm looking for a PowerShell version of this. From what I've seen, I need to get the window's handle, then use that when I navigate to the URL. I want to say this is close, but I'm not sure how to implement it:

```
Get-Process -Name '*edge*' | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowHandle -gt 0 }
```

I'm also trying to use the following code, but, once I get to WindowHandles, I'm not sure what to use for reusing the handle when navigating to the URL.

```
$Handle = $Edge.WindowHandles.[numerous options, but unsure which to use]
$Edge.Navigate().GoToUrl($Handle)
```

Any advice, or resources pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. I tried asking the same question in the SQA Stack Exchange, but they said it should be asked here since they believe it's not "testing". I consider this testing as the solution is not yet in production.

Comment: I am a little confused about your requirement. After you get the window handle of Edge, what do you want to do? Redirect to another site? Or something else?

Comment: @XudongPeng I felt I was very clear in the sentence above the last code example: "I'm also trying to use the following code, but, once I get to WindowHandles, **I'm not sure what to use for reusing the handle when navigating to the URL.**" Even the title is asking for assistance for reusing the same browser window. Take note of the browser window we're communicating in. If I want to reuse this window to run a script that adds another comment, how do I do that with PowerShell and Selenium. I'm sorry if I seem snarky. I'm trying to be clear and get help with this issue. Desperately needed.

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to implement webpage automation using selenium, you need to use webdriver to open the webpage. So in this case, if you want to implement it with existed webpages in Edge , I think you can try win32 api to achieve this requirement. Simply refer to [this case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c3cd3982-ffc5-4c17-98fc-a09c555e121c/get-all-child-window-titles?forum=winserverpowershell).

Comment: I tried that, but it's using `GetForegroundWindow`. This would be fine if the browser window was the starting point of my process. But, it's the end point, so I need to gather data (let's say from an Excel spreadsheet), locate the browser window I already have open, and enter the Excel data into an HTML form on the open browser. I need to be able to locate the open browser to enter the data, not open it each time I gather data. Does that make sense? I feel like I'm losing everyone and it's such an easy concept.